EIP-3855 is not supported in one or more of the RPCs used
I'm trying to run a script in Solidity with pragma solidity 0.8.24 on Anvil with this command:
forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545 --broadcast --account testAccount  --sender 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8

but I got this message:
⠊] Compiling...
[⠒] Compiling 2 files with Solc 0.8.24
[⠢] Solc 0.8.24 finished in 994.41ms
Compiler run successful!
EIP-3855 is not supported in one or more of the RPCs used.
Unsupported Chain IDs: 31337.
Contracts deployed with a Solidity version equal or higher than 0.8.20 might not work properly.
For more information, please see https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3855
Script ran successfully.

== Return ==
0: contract SimpleStorage 0x8464135c8F25Da09e49BC8782676a84730C318bC

## Setting up 1 EVM.

==========================

Chain 31337

Estimated gas price: 1.755958201 gwei

with this code:

pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {SimpleStorage} from "../src/SimpleStorage.sol";

contract DeploySimpleStorage is Script{

    function run() external returns(SimpleStorage) {
        vm.startBroadcast();
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        vm.stopBroadcast();

        return simpleStorage;
    }
}

I tried to change solidity version to 0.8.19 but still got the same message

PUSH 0 was included in the Shanghai hard fork which happened in 2023. You need to sync your local node with this hard forked chain to use PUSH 0.
https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/shanghai.md
